# Colorize image, take the wrong color swift

Tags: swift, image, button, colors, imageview

I want to colorize an image from an imageView. After that I want to set this image to a button.

```
    let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()

    if let myImage = UIImage(named: "ic_star") {
        let tintableImage = myImage.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
        imageView.image = tintableImage
    }

    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor() 

    bestListButton.setImage(imageView.image, forState: .Normal)
```

This is a snippet, that should work, but it colorize my button-image always in blue.
The debugger say that the color doesn't change. And the simulator change it in blue.

It seems that it doesn't have something to do with my backgroundcolor of image.

[image: Button in Yellow]

[image: Button in Blue]

[image: Debugger result: show origin color of button]

**EDIT and (hack) solution**
Okay, it's quite strange. The blue is because in my interface builder was the tintColor blue.
I changed it to white. Now my star is white.

BUT: When I delete my code, the image switch back to black. So the change of color seems just work in combination with interface builder and code.

**EDIT 2** 
Programmatically solution:
     `bestListButton.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Answer (score 0):

Is your image a PNG file?

Try:

```
let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()

if let myImage = UIImage(named: "ic_star") {
    imageView.image = imageView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
}

imageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

bestListButton.setImage(imageView.image, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: yeah it is. My image is in official gylphicon from google material design. Your code throws an error because my imageView is empty... or not empty but it has no image.